# expand=fields($select=***,****) on the SharePoint Graph resource doesn't work and how about filtering?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm playing with the microsoft graph and especially the sharepoint beta api and i am constantly running into issues. I know its beta, but still;)

I'm getting out my expanded fields but i'm not able to select other than id.
`/items?expand=fields(select=id) <-- works`
`/items?expand=fields(select=Title) <-- fails with response being`

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f460cded-46da-468c-a027-f027707a62fc",
      "date": "2017-05-10T09:00:10"
    }
  }
}
```

Further on trying to filter the request with the request `/items?expand=fields&$filter=fields/id eq '421'` doesn't work and after a long period just returns a response without taken the filter into account.

Can someone respond if the experience the same or if my syntax is wrong or whatever would be nice. Thanks in advance. Ole Bergtun

Comment: I've been having the same issue for half year and unfortunately it's still not implemented. You have to get bunch of redundant data and filter them manually. The worst problem is that fetching all of the data is really slow ;/

Comment: I'm guessing they'll have it ready in a couple of days. You must be able to filter even if its a beta. IMO. Looking 4ward to see what happens in the days before the sharepoint virtual summit next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed `/items?expand=fields(select=Title)` to `/items?expand=fields(select%3DTitle)` and it works for me.

Comment: it actually work with = aswell... been using the sharepoint api until now, but happy to see that i can develop with just the graph api